# Why is this mercurial error not in stderr?

Tags: bash, mercurial

Running `hg branch` from a random location without a repository results in the following output:

```
$ hg branch
abort: no repository found in '/home/abe' (.hg not found)!
abort: no repository found in '/home/abe' (.hg not found)!
```

I don't want to see these errors so I tried `hg branch 2>/dev/null` resulting in the following:

```
$ hg branch 2>/dev/null
abort: no repository found in '/home/abe' (.hg not found)!
```

Where is this line coming from if not stderr?
I figured mercurial may echo these errors to standard output as well, so I tried `$ hg branch 2>&1 | awk '{print "test: "$0}'` resulting in:

```
$ hg branch 2>&1 | awk '{print "test: "$0}'
test: abort: no repository found in '/home/abe' (.hg not found)!
abort: no repository found in '/home/abe' (.hg not found)!
```

What I want to do is run `hg branch` and get either the name of the branch I'm in, or no output at all. Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that `hg` is writing directly to the terminal, rather than writing to the standard out and standard error file handles it inherits from its parent process.

Comment: `hg branch 2> /dev/null` works for me as expected (no output when outside a repo, shows branch when inside a repo).  I'm using version 2.0.2

Comment: Is it possible that you have an alias or function for hg? What does `type -a hg` show?

Comment: @lreeder Your comment made me try the same on a different useraccount. I got the same output as you did (none) and started digging around in my .bashrc. Seems it was caused by a previous attempt to add `hg branch` to my PS1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

I attempted to add `hg branch` to my PS1, so I'd know what branch I'm working on while in the terminal.
The first error was a remnant of a previous attempt in my .bashrc.

Silly mistake as always :) Thanks anyway guys!